# Post JSON data from ASP.NET MVC Controller to another URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, post

I tried searching about how to post JSON data from ASP.NET MVC Controller, all in vain.

I have a post method in my Controller, which receives JSON data from the client, and does format validation, before it forwards it another location.

I am not able to figure out how to post data from this method to the other location.

Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the async code for it, so remember to await the method

```
private async Task DoStuff(string s)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri('whatever');
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/whatever/",s);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems unreasonable to round-trip this through the browser. If the action is on the same server, then I would probably abstract the processing code to a shared class and just invoke it after validation, returning the correct response directly from the validation action. If it's on a different server then I'd have the client-side code perform the validation check and, on success, simply POST to the processing action.